# Switching from ASP.NET to Java EE for a large web project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I'm an ASP.NET developer, I'm happy with ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework...

I want to use Java EE in a new web project, but there is a lot of specifications and frameworks (jsf, ejb, hibernate ...),

I'm looking for the best combination of Java EE specification tu use for a big Web Project (I must use HTML5, Javascript, JQuery, Javascript Framework like Telerik Kendo UI, Json, Webservices ...) and I love MVC so I'm looking for the MVC support in Java EE

For now, I decided the deployment server: Debian + Glassfish

I don't care about learning curve, but I do care about stability and performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Web MVC for following reasons.

- Active Community
- Great Documentation
- Ease of learning
- MVC Architecture Supported
- Used in the Industry

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanna go with Spring, MVC being only one of the reasons. I can't tell whether it is the best in the Java landscape (maybe it is, I love it), but given how widely used it is you will most likely find someone able to help whenever you run into something you can't figure out by yourself.

Same applies for Maven when it comes to dependency management. Another viable alternative would be Gradle, but Maven is probably used more widely.

I would also suggest keep your project "Mavenized", i.e. buildable without IDE. That does not mean don't use IDE of course, just make sure it is buildable right after pulling the project from the repository, without starting your IDE.

Just yesterday I read this great article that might help you adopt some good habits right from the start: http://www.jamesward.com/2014/12/03/java-doesnt-suck-youre-just-using-it-wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have very good experience with [Tapestry5](http://tapestry.apache.org/) and for the model layer JDBC templates or JPA([Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/)) which is an ORM tool like Entity Framework.

[Tapestry5](http://tapestry.apache.org/) is a component based framework and it works nice. Great support for AJAX. They have a quite big community and a lot of [components](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/).

You can also use JSF (check [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/index), [richfaces](http://richfaces.jboss.org/)) + [Spring](http://spring.io/)(or CDI) + model layer

If you want something for rapid development use [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) or [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/).

You can also go with Spring MVC which is also a good choice.

For testing use Selenium tests which are just great.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there are many amazing Java EE tools and frameworks, I think the best combination will be using:

**[Spring framework](http://spring.io/)**, **[Hibernate ORM](http://hibernate.org/)** and **[JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html)** (precisely **[Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/)**) because they all have *highly active communities*, *Good documentation* with *great tutorials*.